# Setting number of lags

Tags: python, time-series, package, attributes

I am teaching myself the use of time series in Python.

I was following

https://arch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/unitroot/unitroot_examples.html

I performed

```
adf = ADF(default)
print(adf.summary().as_text())
```

It worked perfectly.

However, when I wanted to change lags like

```
adf.lags = 5
print(adf.summary().as_text())
```

or change the type of trend as in the snip below

[image]

it gives me the following error (same for the trend):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [11], in <module>
----> 1 adf.lags = 5
      2 print(adf.summary().as_text())

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Even when I follow all instructions on the exercise page and recreate it with the data used there I cannot get the lags to change. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please [edit] (copy and paste) the exact and complete error message into your post.

Answer (score 0):

Although documentation (r.t.docs) confirms as you suggested, after a quick look at ADF class inside ARCH/ unitroot/unitroot.py, I believe it takes parameter lags upon creation of the class. I tried and it works.
Instead of adf.lags = 5 you may use version below.

```
adf = ADF(default, lags = 5 )
```

class ADF:

> ```
> def __init__(
>     self,
>     y: ArrayLike,
>     lags: Optional[int] = None,
>     trend: UnitRootTrend = "c",
>     max_lags: Optional[int] = None,
>     method: Literal["aic", "bic", "t-stat"] = "aic",
>     low_memory: Optional[bool] = None,
> ) -> None:
> ```